# Server side, what loses scope when a user navigates away from a page in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Server side, what loses scope and or is eligible for garbage collection when a user navigates away from a page in asp.net mvc 3?

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate on WHY you ask this question (what is hitting you that need to know this).

Comment: @rene - I am trying to find a good way of telling when a page has been navigated away from in order to stop a long running server side poll. It creates tasks and they need to stop as soon as the user navigates away. Javascript is not reliable enough to be in control of the task creation so `onbeforeunload` is not going to cut it. I was hoping to tie to an object whose lifetime is tied to the lifetime of the page.

Comment: Away is away from your site or from a specific page in your site to another specific page in your site?

Comment: Can't you throttle down polling based on your page not being hit for a defined time?

Comment: @rene - 1) Just away from the one specific page. 2) I was actually considering creating that situation if I could not find a reliable object lifetime. Basically have a countdown of tasks that can be run, and then have the user short poll into the countdown to boost it once every minute or so.

Comment: Can't you use an action filter that checks if your user is NOT hitting your specific page and then destruct/unload whatever needs being stopped?

Comment: @rene - Well, the user only technically enters the action one time, so I don't think the filter would apply much here. Once the action is hit, which is from the specific page, then the tasks start.

Comment: There is nothing in scope once the http response is completed and the page delivered. The server wouldn't know if a user navigated away that's a client action. You would need a heartbeat from the client side code in your page which the tasks could monitor as suggested already.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same with what happens on any other compiled code in .Net, if you dispose your objects they will be collected as soon as possible by the Garbage Collector when time tells by the CLR, otherwise, resources are hanging until a good recycle in your IIS happens and/or the CLR in your server needs to clear memory to allocate other resources.

Comment: What about objects which were not initialized in the controller or action, such as the HttpContext?

Comment: well, it depends on what you call 'out of context', InProc session state for example is higly dependent on a certain ASP.Net process, but others like httpContext are also bounded to w3wp which is the process related to IIS.